# Assumptions in Mathematica's NullSpace Command for Symbolic Matrices

Tags: math, matrix, wolfram-mathematica, linear-algebra

When executing Mathematica's NullSpace command on a symbolic matrix, Mathematica makes some assumptions about the variables and I would like to know what they are.

For example,

```
In[1]:= NullSpace[{{a, b}, {c, d}}]

Out[1]= {}
```

but the unstated assumption is that

```
a d != b c.
```

How can I determine what assumptions the NullSpace command uses?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The underlying assumptions, so to speak, are enforced by internal uses of `PossibleZeroQ`. If that function cannot deem an expression to be zero then it will be regarded as nonzero, hence eligible for use as a pivot in row reduction (which is generally what is used for symbolic NullSpace).

---edit---

The question was raised regarding what might be visible in zero testing in symbolic linear algebra. By default the calls to `PossibleZeroQ` go through internal routes. `PossibleZeroQ` was later built on top of those.

There is always a question in Mathematica kernel code development of what should go through the main evaluator loop and what (e.g. for purposes of speed) should short circuit. Only the former is readily traced.

One can influence the process in symbolic linear algebra by specifying a non-default zero test. Could be e.g.

```
myTest[ee_]:= (Print[zerotesting[ee]]; PossibleZeroQ[ee])
```

and then use `ZeroTest->myTest` in `NullSpace`.

---end edit---

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau It is possible to know what calls to what calls  where made to PossibleZeroQ?

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau Is there a more natural way to tell the NullSpace command what polynomials are zero?  I tried

    `In[4]:= m = {{a, b}, {c, d}};`

    `In[5]:= Assuming[a d == b c, NullSpace[m]]`

    `Out[5]= {}`

but it didn't work.

Comment: @Tyson Williams Could do Assuming[a d == b c, 
 NullSpace[m, ZeroTest -> (PossibleZeroQ[Simplify[#]] &)]] to force the assumption to get the needed zero.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau Can you explain why your suggestion (in the previous comment) worked but not mine (in my previous comment)?

Comment: @Tyson Williams The issue is that the default zero test code will not manage to make the needed simplifications in presence of assumptions, in order to show it is zero. It uses Refine internally and not Simplify. A non-default zero test that uses Simplify manages to determine that certain expressions vanish.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau For what seems like such simple/common behavior, I was surprised that you had to spin your own modified function in order to do the job (as opposed to selecting an appropriate setting). I also just noticed that you (probably) didn't make up that function on the spot.  It is in the ZeroTest docs.

Comment: @Tyson Williams Actually I did make it up on the spot. Been a while since I've looked at that section of the ref guide. Should have done so and saved myself a bit of time there. As for requiring a modified test, recall that one of the primary needs of the built-in zero test code is that it be fast. While we fall short in some cases, throwing Simplify into the internals of PossibleZeroQ would mostly just help us to fall short in far more cases.

Answer (score 5):

Found this:

**In this case**, if you expand your matrix by one column, the assumption shows up:

```
NullSpace[{{a, b, 1}, {c, d, 1}}]

{{-((-b+d)/(-b c+a d)),-((a-c)/(-b c+a d)),1}}
```

Perhaps useful in some situations